# Rendering html/js in J2me app?

Tags: java, javascript, html, webkit, java-me

Is is possible to display html document in J2ME mobile app? Is it possible using for example WebKit? I was looking for some webkit's j2me implementation or some tutorial or advice in google but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[BOLT Webkit based Browser](http://boltbrowser.com/dnld.html)

I came across this, but haven't had the time to try it myself, but the reviews seem to be reasonable.
Its closed source but they provide later versions than the current for download for free.

Hope this can shed some light

Answer (score 0):

Try this Framework: [Fire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fire-j2me/)

LWUIT now supports html and CSS in [LWUIT 1.4](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/08/lwuit-14-finally-released.html).